# Django build_absolute_uri() issue : double slashes

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm using [build_absolute_uri()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/request-response/) in order to create the beginning of my download link which is sent by email.

I'm working with django 1.11.20

**My code**

I have in my code, this view which let to create my url :

```
class FileExport(View):

    def my_export(self, request, **kwargs):

        kwargs['user_email'] = request.user.email
        kwargs['user'] = request.user.name
        kwargs['url'] = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('home'))
        get_xls_export.delay(query_params=request.GET, **kwargs)

        return render(request, 'app/celery_export.html')
```

My url kwargs returns : `http://localhost:8000/`.
The `kwargs['url']` is used to create my download link in my message.html file :

```
<a href="{{ url }}{% url 'app:export_download' token=token %}">Download link to your export file</a>
```

I have my project urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='app:home'), name='home'),]
```

I have my urls.py app file like this :

```
app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),

    url(r'^export/(?P<model>[-\w]+)/(?P<search_info>.*)/$', FileExport.as_view(), name='my_export'),
    url(r'^export/(?P<model>[-\w]+)/$', FileExport.as_view(), name='my_export'),
    url(r'^download_export/(?P<token>.*)/$', ExportDownloadView.as_view(), name='export_download'),
]
```

**My issue**

When I receive the email, the link generated inside looks like this :

```
http://localhost:8000//download_export/<my_file>/
```

As you can see, I'm getting this `//` which create an issue. By removing one, it works.

It works on my qualification environment (distant server), but not in localhost. Do you have some ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this because you're effectively calling `request.build_absolute_uri('/')`, which returns `http://localhost:8000/`, then concatenating `/download_export/.../` into it.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, `token` is not known in the view, so create an URL template you can replace the token into:

```py
kwargs['url_template'] = request.build_absolute_uri(resolve_url('app:export_download', token='TOKEN'))
```

and in `get_xls_export`:

```
url = url_template.replace('TOKEN', token)
```

You can then pass this into the template.

Comment: I would like to try your answer, but I'm just getting a little issue. My token is defined in `get_xls_export()` which is a celery task. How I can call `token=token` in `my_export()` if the token is generated in `get_xls_export()` ?

Comment: There we go, @Essex :)

Comment: it seems to work in localhost ! I just have to try now on my qualification server :) I'll come back in few minutes ! Anyway thank you for your answer